# ArcMap bookmarks for legends, scale bar etc

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, legend, scale-bar

I am exporting several GIS dataset maps from a set of several files I have. My images show always the same geographic area. My problem is that, moving from one image to the other one, the legend, north arrow, scale bar and so on are always located in different location (e.g., one is slightly more close to the upper right bottom than the other one).

Is there a way to define a "bookmark" in ArcMap to place these elements always in the same position of the paper image in layout view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each layout element has Properties so to make sure one of them stays in the same location you should just need to go to its Size & Position tab to set the same values.